# $\limsup \frac{a_n}{b_n}<\infty$ show that there is a constant $M>0$ s.t $a_n\le Mb_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_n$ and $b_n$ are sequences of positive numbers such that  $\limsup \frac{a_n}{b_n}<\infty$  show that there is a constant $M>0$ s.t $a_n\le Mb_n$ for all $n\ge 1$

**My idea:**

as i know hat $M=\limsup a_n$ if and only if for all $\epsilon >0$ there is $N\in \mathbb{N}$ so tthat $n\ge N$ implies $a_n<M+\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

If $s_n:=\sup\{a_k/b_k\mid k\geq n\}\in(0,\infty]$ then $(s_n)$ is decreasing and by definition:

$$\limsup (a_n/b_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n$$

So $\limsup (a_n/b_n)<\infty$ implies that $s_N<\infty$ for some $N$.

Then $s_N\leq c$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$ and consequently $a_k/b_k\leq c$ for $k\geq N$.

Then taking $M=\max(c,a_1/b_1,\dots,a_{N-1}/b_{N-1})$ we have $a_n\leq Mb_n$ for every $n$.

Comment: @drhab...thank you sir

Comment: You are very welcome.